# How to rename administrator to custom name entered in textbox using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, updates, powershell-3.0, administrator

```
$admin = [adsi]"WinNT://./Administrator,user"
$admin.psbase.rename("$textbox1.text")
```

Comment: `$admin.psbase.rename("$($textbox1.Text)")`

Comment: `$user = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='$oldName'"`
`$result = $user.Rename($newName)`

try using wmi